# Creating a Step-by-step Custom Membership Provider in ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-membership

I'm making an online Library Management System in ASP.NET. Right now I'm following this http://mattwrock.com/post/2009/10/14/Implementing-custom-Membership-Provider-and-Role-Provider-for-Authinticating-ASPNET-MVC-Applications.aspx (for my user login page).

So how can I modify it to use my own database schema? I already have the table with usename and password. So basically I want user to login using their username, password from the datasource. Also my username is in alphanumeric like 'F123" and the password is 10 characters long.

Could someone explain to me in a step-by-step procedure in creating a Custom Membership Profile?

Thanks in advance ;)

Comment: Why not save a bunch of time and use WIF (Windows Identity Foundation).  Hook that into AD via ADFS, Google via ACS...

Comment: the link provided isn't available anymore

Comment: Hello guys.. can you please look on it... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32924232/how-to-implement-asp-net-membership-in-mvc-project

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/44w5aswa.aspx) ([src code here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6tc47t75.aspx)) - the sample code uses ODBC data provider to fetch/update user information. It should be fairly simple to adapt that for any database/store etc.

Similarly, [this tutorial](http://theintegrity.co.uk/2010/11/asp-net-mvc-2-custom-membership-provider-tutorial-part-1/) is using Entity Framework to get user information from the database.

Comment: OK I'll try this and see what I can do. I'm using SQL server as my datasource. The tutorial is just what I need ;)

Comment: Hello VinaryC.. Can you please look on it.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32924232/how-to-implement-asp-net-membership-in-mvc-project